# Mullion Brass Grommets?

Tags: screws

I have a house that was built 1904. The mullions, etc., were secured with brass woodscrews through brass housings than are much like grommets in appearance. I do not know what they are called.
I need some, as the previous owner started several projects and promptly lost the 'grommets'.

Comment: have a picture?

Comment: These are not ordinary cup washers. The cupping extends into a Forstner drilled hole and has a base against which the head of the screw rests.

Comment: This might be a better fit for DIY.

Comment: @rob, I think we may have been over this before, but I can't seem to close vote and migrate to anything but meta WW. Is there a way to ad DIY to the list?

Comment: @Doresoom I'm checking with the DIY mods to see if they think it's a good fit. If so, any of the mods here can migrate it. Also I looked into adding DIY to the list, and as it turns out, a beta site doesn't get to have a migration target list. In the meantime feel free to flag and mention the target site you think is most appropriate (I'm guessing it'll almost always be DIY).

Comment: Google "Lee Valley Countersunk Washers" if in N. America; in the UK, "brass turned screw cups". Can't help with any other regions...

Comment: @sam bowlturner already mentioned it, but would you please add a picture?

Answer (score 7):

The washers you're looking for are "countersunk washers" or sometimes "brass screw cups". Here's [an image from Lee Valley](http://www.leevalley.com/US/wood/page.aspx?p=47230&cat=3,41306,41316&ap=1):

[image: countersunk washers]

and [another from High Torque](http://hightorquefasteners.co.uk/countersunk-washers-p-118.html):

[image: countersunk washers 2]

Unfortunately, the countersunk versions that you want are often mixed up with regular old surface finishing washers like these:

[image: finishing washers]

Answer (score 0):

This: http://www.jamestowndistributors.com/userportal/show_product.do?pid=1911&familyName=Brass+Finish+Washers

is what you want.  The place I used to get these seems to have gone bye-bye.
This is traditional (circa 1910) hardware for doors.  If you google for 'brass screw decorative washers'  you can find suppliers.